# MAX(ID) with IN() comparison function performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stumbled upon a performance issue with this query. I've stared at this problem for a long time now scratching my head. This query was actually pretty fast at one point, but once data grew, it became slower and slower. The 'Posts' table has +5 million rows, the 'Items' table has +6000 rows. These tables are growing constantly on a daily basis.

```
SELECT Posts.itemID, Items.itemName, Items.itemImage, Items.guid, Posts.price,
Posts.quantity, Posts.date, Games.name, Items.profit FROM Items 
INNER JOIN Posts ON Items.itemID=Posts.itemID 
INNER JOIN Games ON Posts.gameID=Games.gameID 
WHERE Posts.postID IN (SELECT MAX(postID) FROM Posts GROUP BY itemID) AND Posts.gameID=:gameID 
    AND Posts.price BETWEEN :price_min AND :price_max
    AND Posts.quantity BETWEEN :quant_min AND :quant_max
    AND Items.profit BETWEEN :profit_min AND :profit_max
ORDER BY Items.profit DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

In the code I've split up the query and sub query into two. Together they were performing slower. This was all good and well, until the data in both the Posts and Items started growing. The 'where' statements that I've put in ** get concatenate depending on what filters are set.

Here's the EXPLAIN that I get. (This is the query without the sub query)
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1jxMdMfC35VeDBEbnJISmNGb3c/edit?usp=sharing

**SHOW INDEX FROM Posts**:

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Posts |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | postID      | A         |     5890249 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Posts |          1 | itemID   |            1 | itemID      | A         |       16453 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Posts |          1 | gameID   |            1 | gameID      | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**SHOW INDEX FROM Items**;

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Items |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | itemID      | A         |        6452 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**SHOW INDEX FROM Games;**

```
 +-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
 | Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
 +-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
 | Games |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | gameID      | A         |        2487 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
 +-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Is there anyway I can make this query faster? Do you guys have any advice? Is there a better way of writing this query? All help is appreciated.

EXPLAIN Proposed Query:

```
  +----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
  | id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref                        | rows    | Extra                                        |
  +----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
  |  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                       |      19 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
  |  1 | PRIMARY     | p          | eq_ref | PRIMARY,itemID,gameID | PRIMARY | 4       | q.postID                   |       1 |                                              |
  |  1 | PRIMARY     | i          | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 2       | db323245342342345.p.itemID |       1 | Using where                                  |
  |  1 | PRIMARY     | g          | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 4       | db323245342342345.p.gameID |       1 | Using where                                  |
  |  2 | DERIVED     | p          | ref    | itemID,gameID         | gameID  | 2       |                            | 2945124 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
  |  2 | DERIVED     | i          | eq_ref | PRIMARY               | PRIMARY | 2       | db323245342342345.p.itemID |       1 | Using where                                  |
  +----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+---------+---------+----------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Maybe your stats are out of date. Use ANALYZE TABLE command to update them for each table in your query.

Comment: Thought that's what it was too, but it says it's 'OK'

Comment: `(SELECT MAX(postID) FROM Posts GROUP BY itemID)` : the `GROUP BY` looks useless to me.

Comment: I've only grouped them because the Posts table can have the same itemID multiple times (Basically tracks daily stats) and we want the latest postIDs for the latest information in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but try moving the subquery to the end of your where clause and also try making it a correlated subquery. Move the filter on Items to the top.

```
SELECT 
 p1.itemID, 
 Items.itemName, 
 Items.itemImage, 
 Items.guid, 
 p1.price,
 p1.quantity, 
 p1.date, 
 Games.name, 
 Items.profit 
FROM Items 
INNER JOIN Posts p1 ON Items.itemID=p1.itemID 
INNER JOIN Games ON p1.gameID=Games.gameID 
WHERE Items.profit BETWEEN :profit_min AND :profit_max
    AND p1.gameID=:gameID 
    AND p1.price BETWEEN :price_min AND :price_max
    AND p1.quantity BETWEEN :quant_min AND :quant_max
    AND p1.postID IN (SELECT MAX(p2.postID) FROM posts p2 WHERE p2.itemID = p1.ItemID GROUP BY p2.itemID)
ORDER BY 
 Items.profit DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

- Also, make sure you create an index on Posts(itemID, gameID, postID)

Comment: Hi @sl0ppy!
I've tried your query but it's also taking quite a bit of time. I'm assuming doing max() on a 4+ million row table takes a bit of time. Maybe I can find a different solution by restructuring the database.

Comment: @roadrunner: Do you have the index that I suggested? Note that it is a composite index and not individual indexes on each column. Also, yes that will be slow unless you can find a way to filter out that Max() subquery a bit more. Normally, I would suggest you create that index with PostID DESC, but MySQL doesn't support DESC order.

Comment: Sorry for the slow replies. Thanks for being so patient. Using the composite index was indeed a lot faster. I decided to go for a different approach though. Decided to denormalize one of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rewrite it with `JOIN`. Something like

```sql
SELECT p.itemID, 
       i.itemName, 
       i.itemImage, 
       i.guid, 
       p.price,
       p.quantity, 
       p.date, 
       g.name, 
       i.profit 
  FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(postID) postID 
      FROM Posts p JOIN Items i
        ON p.itemID = i.itemID
     WHERE p.gameID = :gameID 
       AND p.price    BETWEEN :price_min  AND :price_max
       AND p.quantity BETWEEN :quant_min  AND :quant_max 
       AND i.profit   BETWEEN :profit_min AND :profit_max
     GROUP BY itemID
) q JOIN Posts p 
    ON q.postID = p.postID JOIN Items i
    ON p.itemID = i.itemID JOIN Games g
    ON p.gameID = g.gameID
 ORDER BY i.profit DESC 
 LIMIT 0, 20
```

Comment: Hi peterm. I was just testing the query. It seems to be performing similiar to the other one. It takes around 5-6 seconds to execute. Could it be something else that's making these queries slow?

Comment: @roadrunner Hi. Do you have all necessary indices (on columns that you join and you filter in `WHERE` clause)? Can you post full `EXPLAIN` on  the proposed query and `SHOW INDEX FROM Posts; SHOW INDEX FROM Items;` **in text format**?

Comment: Thanks @peterm . I've done what you've asked. All the information should be in the main post.